# Trigger execution

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a table with different prices for each item. Each item have prices 0, 1, 2, 3. I need to change price 3 when price 0 is changed. Price 3 = Price 0 + 20%. I made this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_PG_Change_Price3

ON ItemSellingPrices

AFTER UPDATE

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE
    @Item NVARCHAR(25),
    @CostPrice FLOAT;

SELECT
    @Item = ItemID,
    @CostPrice = UnitPrice
FROM
    inserted
WHERE PriceLineID = 0

UPDATE ItemSellingPrices
SET     UnitPrice = @CostPrice*1.2
WHERE ItemID = @Item AND PriceLineID = 3

END
```

It turns out that when I run an UPDATE via SQL query directly, everything runs perfectly. But when the price 0 is updated via ERP nothing happens. Anyone have any ideas? (MS SQL Server)
It seems that the trigger does not fire when the update is done via ERP system.

Comment: I have no intention of taking the question out of topic or with little information. The fact is I can not activate this trigger when the table is changed by my ERP system and do not know how to approach the subject. Sorry...

Comment: I found my problem! Every time I change the price 0, ERP upgrade all prices. Therefore  after change price 0 the trigger is fired, but price 3 was again replaced by ERP. I changed the trigger to change the price 3 when he himself is changed and it worked! Sorry I posted the question but I have little experience thought was a flaw in the design of the trigger but only had to better understand the inner workings of ERP and make the trigger accordingly. Thank all anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_PG_Change_Price3
ON ItemSellingPrices
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT i.ItemID, i.UnitPrice INTO #temp
    FROM inserted i INNER JOIN deleted d 
    ON i.ItemID = d.ItemID
    WHERE i.PriceLineID = 0
    AND   i.UnitPrice <> d.UnitPrice


    UPDATE T
    SET T.UnitPrice = i.UnitPrice * 1.2
    FROM ItemSellingPrices T INNER JOIN #temp i
    ON T.ItemID = i.ItemID
    WHERE T.PriceLineID = 3

END
```

**Without Temp Table**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_PG_Change_Price3
ON ItemSellingPrices
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE T
    SET T.UnitPrice = i.UnitPrice * 1.2
    FROM ItemSellingPrices T 
            INNER JOIN (    SELECT i.ItemID, i.UnitPrice
                            FROM inserted i INNER JOIN deleted d 
                            ON i.ItemID = d.ItemID
                            WHERE i.PriceLineID = 0
                            AND   i.UnitPrice <> d.UnitPrice
                        ) i
    ON T.ItemID = i.ItemID
    WHERE T.PriceLineID = 3

END
```

Comment: I'm sorry @M.Ali, but have the same result with both...

Comment: Can you show some sample data and desired output, I dont see anything wrong with this code maybe sample date will help to diagnose it better.

Comment: This code is perfect, I think. When I made an update via SQL, like:    `UPDATE ItemSellingPrices
    SET  UnitPrice = 6500
   WHERE ItemID = '0012' AND PriceLineID = 0` I have a Price 3 with 7800. But the problem is when I made the change via my ERP System nothing happens...

Comment: Well then you need to look into your ERP system. I am sorry I wont be able to help you with that :) if the answer helped you can accept it thank you.

Comment: In that case you need to tweak your ERP system settings maybe it turns off any triggers when issuing update statements.

Comment: Once I figured out my problem, I will accept this as a valid response because it taught me another way of doing this trigger. Thanks @M.Ali